# Restful API: Change date format from unixtime to ISO-8601

Tags: database, datetime, 8

Applying the date_iso8601 Drupal function in a simple process_callbacks on the public_fields in the class file for each date field works to convert the output/display of the date format, but does not allow that format to be used for filtering by the date value.

```
  'process_callbacks' => array(
    'date_iso8601',
  ),
```

So we need to figure out how to make the query filter use the ISO 8601 date format and support things like partial matches using just YYYY-MM-DD and ensure different operators work as well (>, <, >=, <=).